# Unwanted separation in an equation

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathtools

I have an equation with an intersection which has multiple limit levels, like this,

```
\[
\langle H, H'\rangle = \bigcap_{\substack{
L \leq G, \\
H \cup H' \subseteq L.
}}L
\]
```

[image]

It compiles nicely, but that code prints *L* and the equal sign too far apart from the intersection. Is there a way to eliminate those spaces in order to make the equation look better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mh/mathtools.pdf) provides the macro `\mathclap` (and also `\crampedclap`, `\smashoperator`) for precisely this occasion (see pages 4–7 of the manual):

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
%...
\begin{equation*}
  \langle H, H'\rangle = \bigcap_{\mathclap{\substack{
  L \leq G, \\
  H \cup H' \subseteq L.
  }}}L
\end{equation*}
```

> [image: Result of LaTeX example]

Answer (score 6):

Try `\usepackage{mathtools}` and

```
\[
\langle H, H'\rangle = \smashoperator{\bigcap_{\substack{
L \leq G, \\
H \cup H' \subseteq L.
}}}L
\]
```